# Clear terminal history in Pydroid 3

Tags: pydroid

I could not figure out how to clear Pydroid's terminal history.

I tried hictory -c and history -d and history -w and that does not work. Clear and cls are not available commands.

Comment: terminal scrollback? shell history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured where the history is stored in a file. The following commands worked for me. You must restart Pydroid to see the change.

```
/storage/emulated/0 $ cd ~
~/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/app_HOME $ ls -a
.             ..            .ash_history
~/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/app_HOME $ rm .ash_history
~/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/app_HOME $
```

Answer (score 0):

With the console

> > > print("\033[H\033[J")

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).